# No response or error from AFAmazonS3Client

Tags: objective-c, macos, amazon-s3, afnetworking

I am trying to get the latest version of AFAmazonS3Client to upload a file to S3 using a command line osx application, the following is my code. This is not the code shown on the git readme, as the readme code doesn't match the header definitions for the classes. When I run this code, nothing happens no errors no logs nothing. I have traced the queue and it remains active for the default 60 timeout and then shows no queued activities after that. If someone could post a working example it would be very helpful, or an update to the readme file on git which matches the latest version:

```
        _s3Manager = [[AFAmazonS3Manager alloc] initWithAccessKeyID:@"My-Access-Key"
                                                             secret:@"My-Secret-Key"];

        _s3Manager.requestSerializer.region = AFAmazonS3USStandardRegion;
        _s3Manager.requestSerializer.bucket = @"Bucket-Name";

        [_s3Manager postObjectWithFile:outputPath
                      destinationPath:@"/configtest.json"
                           parameters:nil
                             progress:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
                                 NSLog(@"%f%% Uploaded", (totalBytesWritten / (totalBytesExpectedToWrite * 1.0f) * 100));
                             }
                              success:^(id responseObject) {
                                  NSLog(@"Upload Complete");
                              }
                              failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                              }];
```

I have tried for a day to get this to work, searched all the forums to no avail, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I am having the same problem.